# ASP.NET Boilerplate Identity Server API Access Token

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, zero, abp

I have successfully enabled Identity Server in ASP.Net Boilerplate and called it with a JS client as described by Identity Server docs http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_javascript_client.html . After logging on and getting an access token I cannot use this access token to access the API as I get 401.

I was unable to complete the final step as shown by Identity Server example. Because My projects throws an error on startup saying Identityserver already registered. I am assuming without this step my token is not generated correctly. However have not been able to work out how I should configure ABP to do the same thing.

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ApiName = "api1";
 });
```

Any help appreciated :)

The exact error I get is  **401 (Unauthorized)**. If i exchange the token for one generated through /api/TokenAuth/Authenticate the call works.

**The Token generated through Identity server is** "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNhODAzNTUzNzNlNDVhMzRmNTI3MzJmM2ZjZWNjZTQ4IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTExNTgyMjYsImV4cCI6MTU1MTE2MTgyNiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo2MjExNCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NjIxMTQvcmVzb3VyY2VzIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoianMiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTUxMTU3MTcwLCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCIsInByb2ZpbGUiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.LBJ5KfiOGjMSWlpsWbXLuGBnd0RHq07IWM7npYGPOBm38ENeZkzLErgwalTFH7acOOa8rHymfTFRBVQgO1sEy-nnxn-iPmjstKABu2Xe1o-qlsrU7K7mxN1FLKJWksWBty983TZ-WLrK9pXEHjN9LGeBFY-Qx_RPFOVu4gattjgNI05-J3a2dsnON_bJfvsXPL2ktUa_od-uqi9AXnWY_kJA-5xh1rjMP6pf740tMQJjhMGAIitQHbWiCfmvvPjX6bzBnMXFJpmiVT_hZsZ76zoQskLRQz8Zn-IfVhU9VM-8U7B6PKUaVFs4-VA2ia9VVwxuSs1gJoC9RwMqKYmX_g"

My Client is being registered with these properties.

```
        var client = new Client
        {
            ClientId = "js",
            ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            RequirePkce = true,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            RequireConsent = true,
            RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/index.html" },
            AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5003" },

            AllowedScopes =
            { 
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "Apps"                    
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: And paste the token you use in the authorize header please

Comment: The exact error I get is  GET http://localhost:62114/api/services/app/Apps/GetAll 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: How did you use the token?